# Problem running an Business Api Ecosystem whitin Docker caused by a MySql SSL Certificate error

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, ssl-certificate

I am trying to run an Business Api Ecosystem ( https://business-api-ecosystem.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docker-guide.html) within docker on a Ubuntu VM, and when i try to docker-compose up everything start but i see some errors caused by MySql,more exactly

```
✔ Network baedocker_default      Created                                 0.1s 
 ✔ Container baedocker-apis_db-1  Crea...                                 0.1s 
 ✔ Container baedocker-apis-1     Created                                 0.1s 
Attaching to baedocker-apis-1, baedocker-apis_db-1
baedocker-apis_db-1  | 2023-09-15 11:28:50+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.1.0-1.el8 started.
baedocker-apis_db-1  | 2023-09-15 11:28:50+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
baedocker-apis_db-1  | 2023-09-15 11:28:50+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.1.0-1.el8 started.
baedocker-apis_db-1  | '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
baedocker-apis_db-1  | 2023-09-15T11:28:50.885821Z 0 [System] [MY-015015] [Server] MySQL Server - start.
baedocker-apis_db-1  | 2023-09-15T11:28:51.108402Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
baedocker-apis_db-1  | 2023-09-15T11:28:51.110458Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.1.0) starting as process 1
baedocker-apis_db-1  | 2023-09-15T11:28:51.127028Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
baedocker-apis_db-1  | 2023-09-15T11:28:51.369859Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
baedocker-apis_db-1  | 2023-09-15T11:28:51.692657Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
baedocker-apis_db-1  | 2023-09-15T11:28:51.692705Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
baedocker-apis_db-1  | 2023-09-15T11:28:51.700259Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
baedocker-apis_db-1  | 2023-09-15T11:28:51.737316Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
baedocker-apis_db-1  | 2023-09-15T11:28:51.737436Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.1.0'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
baedocker-apis-1     | Waiting for domain1 to start ....
baedocker-apis-1     | Successfully started the domain : domain1
baedocker-apis-1     | domain  Location: /glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1
baedocker-apis-1     | Log File: /glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/server.log
baedocker-apis-1     | Admin Port: 4848
baedocker-apis-1     | Command start-domain executed successfully.
baedocker-apis-1     | Creating Database tables
baedocker-apis-1     | mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
baedocker-apis-1     | ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: unknown error number
baedocker-apis-1     | mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
baedocker-apis-1     | ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: unknown error number
baedocker-apis-1     | mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
baedocker-apis-1     | ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: unknown error number
baedocker-apis-1     | mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
baedocker-apis-1     | ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: unknown error number
baedocker-apis-1     | mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
baedocker-apis-1     | ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: unknown error number
baedocker-apis-1     | mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
baedocker-apis-1     | ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: unknown error number
baedocker-apis-1     | mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
baedocker-apis-1     | ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: unknown error number
baedocker-apis-1     | mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
baedocker-apis-1     | ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: unknown error number
baedocker-apis-1     | Deploying APIs
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     |   RAN: /glassfish4/glassfish/bin/asadmin deploy --force false --contextroot DSProductCatalog --name DSProductCatalog DSProductCatalog.war
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     |   STDOUT:
baedocker-apis-1     | Command deploy failed.
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     |   STDERR:
baedocker-apis-1     | remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
baedocker-apis-1     | Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: The connection could not be allocated: Communications link failure
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     | The last packet successfully received from the server was 59 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 38 milliseconds ago.
baedocker-apis-1     | Error Code: 0. Please see server.log for more details.
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     | API DSPRODUCTCATALOG2 could not be deployed
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     |   RAN: /glassfish4/glassfish/bin/asadmin deploy --force false --contextroot DSProductOrdering --name DSProductOrdering DSProductOrdering.war
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     |   STDOUT:
baedocker-apis-1     | Command deploy failed.
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     |   STDERR:
baedocker-apis-1     | remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
baedocker-apis-1     | Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: The connection could not be allocated: Communications link failure
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     | The last packet successfully received from the server was 18 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 17 milliseconds ago.
baedocker-apis-1     | Error Code: 0. Please see server.log for more details.
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     | API DSPRODUCTORDERING could not be deployed
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     |   RAN: /glassfish4/glassfish/bin/asadmin deploy --force false --contextroot DSProductInventory --name DSProductInventory DSProductInventory.war
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     |   STDOUT:
baedocker-apis-1     | Command deploy failed.
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     |   STDERR:
baedocker-apis-1     | remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
baedocker-apis-1     | Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: The connection could not be allocated: Communications link failure
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     | The last packet successfully received from the server was 4 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 2 milliseconds ago.
baedocker-apis-1     | Error Code: 0. Please see server.log for more details.
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     | API DSPRODUCTINVENTORY could not be deployed
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     |   RAN: /glassfish4/glassfish/bin/asadmin deploy --force false --contextroot DSPartyManagement --name DSPartyManagement DSPartyManagement.war
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     |   STDOUT:
baedocker-apis-1     | Command deploy failed.
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     |   STDERR:
baedocker-apis-1     | remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
baedocker-apis-1     | Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: The connection could not be allocated: Communications link failure
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     | The last packet successfully received from the server was 3 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 2 milliseconds ago.
baedocker-apis-1     | Error Code: 0. Please see server.log for more details.
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     | API DSPARTYMANAGEMENT could not be deployed
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     |   RAN: /glassfish4/glassfish/bin/asadmin deploy --force false --contextroot DSBillingManagement --name DSBillingManagement DSBillingManagement.war
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     |   STDOUT:
baedocker-apis-1     | Command deploy failed.
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     |   STDERR:
baedocker-apis-1     | remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
baedocker-apis-1     | Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: The connection could not be allocated: Communications link failure
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     | The last packet successfully received from the server was 4 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 3 milliseconds ago.
baedocker-apis-1     | Error Code: 0. Please see server.log for more details.
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     | API DSBILLINGMANAGEMENT could not be deployed
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     |   RAN: /glassfish4/glassfish/bin/asadmin deploy --force false --contextroot DSCustomerManagement --name DSCustomerManagement DSCustomerManagement.war
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     |   STDOUT:
baedocker-apis-1     | Command deploy failed.
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     |   STDERR:
baedocker-apis-1     | remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
baedocker-apis-1     | Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: The connection could not be allocated: Communications link failure
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     | The last packet successfully received from the server was 3 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 2 milliseconds ago.
baedocker-apis-1     | Error Code: 0. Please see server.log for more details.
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     | API DSCUSTOMER could not be deployed
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     |   RAN: /glassfish4/glassfish/bin/asadmin deploy --force false --contextroot DSUsageManagement --name DSUsageManagement DSUsageManagement.war
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     |   STDOUT:
baedocker-apis-1     | Command deploy failed.
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     |   STDERR:
baedocker-apis-1     | remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
baedocker-apis-1     | Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: The connection could not be allocated: Communications link failure
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     | The last packet successfully received from the server was 6 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 5 milliseconds ago.
baedocker-apis-1     | Error Code: 0. Please see server.log for more details.
baedocker-apis-1     | 
baedocker-apis-1     | API DSUSAGEMANAGEMENT could not be deployed
baedocker-apis-1     | 26.5701239109
baedocker-apis-1     | biz_apis finished successfully.
```

I have tried to add custom ssl certifies, and to modify the docker-compose.yml that is :

```
version: '3'

services:
    apis_db:
        image: mysql:latest
        ports:
            - "3333:3306"
        volumes:
            - ./apis-data:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Parola213!

    apis:
        image: conwetlab/biz-ecosystem-apis
        ports:
            - "4848:4848"
            - "8080:8080"
        links:
            - apis_db
        depends_on:
            - apis_db
        volumes:
            - ./apis-wars:/apis/wars-ext
            # Provided if configured by volume rather than by environment
            # - ./apis-config:/etc/default/tmf/
        environment:
            - BAE_SERVICE_HOST=http://proxy.docker:8004/
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Parola213!
            - MYSQL_HOST=apis_db

``
```

Comment: It looks like it is using a very old version of MySQL Connector/J (5.1.39) and the release notes say it is _"suitable for use with MySQL Server versions 5.5, 5.6, and 5.7"_. You are using `mysql:latest`, which I think is now 8.1.

Comment: Hmm, but i installed running the script that they gave, ill try to do it manually using an old mysql version.

Comment: Just change `mysql:latest` to `mysql:5.7` for `apis_db`. This is not a good solution, as MySQL 5.7 goes EOL next month. Maybe try asking the maintainer of the product.